# Minimum number of steps required to invert sequence

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

There are numbers from 1 to n, which are inverted such that it results in numbers from n to 1. If only two consecutive numbers are stapled at a time and are inverted, how many moves are required?

Comment: If the posted answers are the intended ones, this is a fair question. However, its wording needs work. "Inverted" indicates "turned", & if $n$ things are inverted, that means each thing is inverted, not that the things' order is changed. And "stapled" needs to be either defined or replaced by a word whose meaning is clear.

Comment: What about just using the function: $f(x) = n+1-x$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to overlap any previous numbers you have to swap with it atleast once.
Now for every number at pos p you have atleast n-p-1 numbers to be swapped with.

So solution will be

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{n*(n-1)}{2}$$

Example for 5 4 3 2 1

> 5 needs to be swapped with 4 numbers
>  4 needs to be swapped with 3 numbers
>  3 needs to be swapped with 2 numbers
>  2 needs to be swapped with 1 number.
>
>  Thus 1+2+3+4 = 10

Answer (score 1):

from the way you described a move I can say there is two cases :

*n* is even : then we have to do n/2 moves

*n* is odd : there is then (n-1)/2 moves.

Comment: Your answer looks like it would be correct, except for the word "consecutive" in the question.

Comment: yes you're right. It seems I passed over that word too quickly !